# Finding the normal distribution given a specific amount of objects

Tags: statistics

If brick wieghts are normally distribution in kgs with $E[X]=0.96$ and $\sigma = 0.045$, Find the distribution of $Y$ if $Y$ is the mean of $9$ bricks.

So I have
$X \sim N(0.96,0.045^2)$, but I'm not sure what to make of the specified number of bricks ($9$)

Should I care about that? I'm thinking about normalizing it to the standard normal distribution but I'm not sure how that would help. Actually, if that is the correct thing to do, could someone explain why that is the intuitive correct thing to do, because right now its just a random thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are iid $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variables, then
\begin{equation}
\overline X = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}\sim \mathcal N\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)
\end{equation}
Given that $n=9, \mu = 0.96$ and $\sigma = 0.045$, plug in the values to get the distribution of the mean.

Comment: what does iid mean? Ans the thing is, i don't understand why you would divide the variance by the number of bricks

Comment: @user71207, iid means "Independent and Identically Distributed". For your second question, note that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are distributed as $\mathcal N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $\mathcal N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ respectively, then $X_1+X_2\sim\mathcal N(\mu_1+\mu_2,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$ and $cX_1\sim\mathcal N(c\mu,c^2\sigma^2)$. Above result follows from this general result.

Comment: what does that $c$ mean in this case. Yes ok, I could use that and take $X_1$ up to $X_9$, but then the means would end up as $9\mu$, which isn't very helpful.

Comment: Mainly Im confused about why the mean stays the same but sd changes - I guess my intuition nags me that it would and should stay the same no matte the number of bricks

Comment: @user71207 Since the means and variances add up, the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^9X_i=9\overline X$ becomes $\mathcal N(9\mu,9\sigma^2)$. Taking $c=\frac19$, the distribution of $\overline X$ becomes $\mathcal N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{9})$ and we're done.

Comment: thanks for that explanation. I see now