# Finding a constant using the table of normal distibution

Tags: statistics, solution-verification

Given $X\sim N(\mu,36)$, a random sample of $50$ of $X$ has mean $20.2$. Find $L$ if $P(\bar{X}<L)=0.95$

I first tried to normalize it so I could use the $z$ score value from the table:

$$P\left(Z<\frac{L-mean}{sd}\right)=P\left(Z<\frac{L-20.2}{\frac{3}{25}}\right)$$

The equivalent $z$ to probability of $0.95$ is $1.64$. Then

$$z=1.94=\frac{L-20.2}{\frac{3}{50}},\:L=21.02$$

Which is not far off the answer, but something is wrong. Can someone help me find that out?

Comment: The sample mean has standard deviation $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Could you explain why and how please? Especially why is $n$ square-rooted: In previous questions, I didn't need to do that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088928/finding-the-normal-distribution-given-a-specific-amount-of-objects/4088938?noredirect=1#comment8450007_4088938

Comment: Nevermind, it was a simple $\sigma = \sqrt{Var(X)}$